# How do I echo the text that the user entered?

Tags: php

So instead of echo `"Invalid specialization entered. Please check your spelling.";`

I would like to echo `"[THE TEXT THAT THE USER ENTERED] is not a valid spec."`

All help appreciated. Tell me if I was not clear and if you need more info.

```php
if (
$spec == "Protection" || $spec == "Arms" || $spec == "Fury" ||
$spec == "Shadow" || $spec == "Discipline" || $spec == "Holy" || 
$spec == "Frost" || $spec == "Fire" || $spec == "Arcane" ||
$spec == "Destruction" || $spec == "Demonology" || $spec == "Affliction" || 
$spec == "Subtlety" || $spec == "Combat" || $spec == "Assassination" || 
$spec == "Restoration" || $spec == "Feral" || $spec == "Balance" || $spec == "Guardian" ||
$spec == "Enhancement" || $spec == "Restoration" || $spec == "Elemental" ||
$spec == "Marksmanship" || $spec == "Beast Mastery" || $spec == "Survival")



{
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Valid spec entered.";
}


else {  
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Invalid specialization entered. Please check your spelling.";
}`
```

Comment: just concat $spec no? o.O

Comment: If you have solved the problem, please consider adding an answer and accepting it so that your answer might help others in the future. I'm sure you've had the frustration of finding someone online that had the exact same problem as you but didn't go into any detail about how they solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, instead of doing lots of `||` insert them in an array and check if the user inserted one of them through [`in_array`](https://php.net/in_array):

```
$arrSpecs = array
(
    'Protection', 
    'Arms', 
    'Fury', 
    'Shadow', 
    'Discipline', 
    'Holy', 
    'Frost', 
    'Fire', 
    'Arcane', 
    'Destruction', 
    'Demonology', 
    'Affliction', 
    'Subtlety', 
    'Combat', 
    'Assassination', 
    'Restoration', 
    'Feral', 
    'Balance', 
    'Guardian', 
    'Enhancement', 
    'Restoration', 
    'Elemental', 
    'Marksmanship', 
    'Beast Mastery', 
    'Survival'
);

if(in_array($spec, $arrSpecs)
{
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Valid spec entered.";
}
else {  
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Invalid specialization entered ($spec). Please check your spelling.";
}`
```

Be aware that if the directive [register_globals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) is set to `off` (As of default from PHP 4.2.0), you must get user input through [`$_GET`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) or [`$_POST`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) accordingly to the method used in your form, e.g.:

```
$spec = !empty($_GET['spec']) ? $_GET['spec'] : '';
```

Comment: Ohh, that seems way easier. Still very new since I started the other day. Thanks for the info :)